# Is there a way to be notified about completion of an async operation?

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I am performing [data export](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-export/export-data-to-storage) in asynchronous mode and getting an operation ID of a task. I understand that I can retrieve the status of the operation by using `.show operations` command, but is there any better way of awaiting for operation completion than polling? The ways I can think of would be a webhook, a message over a queue/event hub, or other event-driven approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such notification by ADX. You can use event grid notifications to listen to blob created events, for the exported blobs, but there's no notification for the export *completion*.